# YII2 Restful post and TimestampBehavior

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I'm  trying to use TimestampBehavior in my Restful API created Yii2, but when I create a new entity using the POST endpoint, the return data is quite strange.

```
{
  "i18_id": 3,
  "language": "es",
  "text": "un test de traducción",
  "created_at": {
    "expression": "NOW()",
    "params": [ ]
  },
  "updated_at": {
    "expression": "NOW()",
    "params": [ ]
  },
  "id": 2
}
```

When I GET the entity later everything looks fine.

Here is how I've declared the Behavior in my model:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'timestamp' => [
            'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
            ],
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: An easy fix would be to replace `new Expression('NOW()')` with `time()`.

Comment: Could it be mistype in Expression namespace? It should be yii\db\Expression.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have added the Entry in your test and return the model just added.

I guess a simple `$model->refresh();` will fill the values.

See official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#refresh%28%29-detail).

Comment: Doing `$model->refresh()` and stuff like `id` is filled in correctly, but still seeing the 'expression' stuff...

Comment: Nope, scratch that. Looked again and you were right all along! I was doing model refresh in another action but not here. Looked wrong the first time! `$model->refresh()` is the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this value:

```
'value' => function() { return date('U'); },
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more about why your answer works? This will help further readers that stumble upon your answer.

Comment: @Cristik i'ts quite easy. $value is the expression that will generate the timestamp. I didn't get working the NOW expression too but solved changing that with a funtion that return current time in a Linux console. source: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/684/save-and-display-date-time-fields-in-different-formats-in-yii2/

Comment: Thanks, can you add these details to your answer also?

Answer (score 0):

So finally I've found a good solution thanks to @BHoft suggestion.

Mainly I'm using the rest ActiveController and my api needs to return the date after creation using a date format, so the `date('U')` doesn't work in my case because it doesn't return the date on the right format.

What I've done is that I've added an `afterSave` to my model.

```
public function afterSave ($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    if ($insert)
        $this->refresh();
}
```